# Body of the mail in PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I can able to display some HTML contents in the body of the mail in PHP using the below code

`$body = file_get_contents('yourfile.html');`

But I wanted to retrieve and display the user password in the body of the mail, stored in database.

Please give some suggestions.

Comment: for god's sake, please don't tell me, that the passwords are stored in plaintext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Heres my way of doing it. hope it helps :)
To Select the Password from Database:

```
// connect to the mysql server
$mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DB);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->conect_errno . ')'
    . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');

// query the password (please dont store passwords plaintext! :)
// fetch an assoc array of the selected row afterwards
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE user='j.doe'");
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// retrive password and map it to a variable you can use in your mail body
$userPassword = $row['password'];
```